# Outsource properties of jar application

Tags: java, apache, maven, properties

I use [Apache Common Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/index.html) : it's ok and simple and efficient

```
{
private static final String ENV_FILE = "basedir_conf_dir";
private static final String CONFIGURATION_FILE = "configuration/appli.properties";
private static final String DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILE = "configuration/default-appli.properties";

private static ConfigurationManager configurationManager = null;
private CompositeConfiguration compositeConfiguration;

private ConfigurationManager() throws ConfigurationException {
    Parameters params1 = new Parameters();

    compositeConfiguration = new CompositeConfiguration();
    ConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration> builder1 = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class).configure(params1.fileBased()
            .setURL(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(CONFIGURATION_FILE)).setListDelimiterHandler(new DefaultListDelimiterHandler(';')));

    Configuration fichierConfigEnvironnement;
    fichierConfigEnvironnement = builder1.getConfiguration();

    compositeConfiguration.addConfiguration(fichierConfigEnvironnement);
    Parameters params2 = new Parameters();

    ConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration> builder2 = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class).configure(params2.fileBased()
            .setURL(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILE)).setListDelimiterHandler(new DefaultListDelimiterHandler(';')));

    Configuration fichierConfigEquipeDev = builder2.getConfiguration();
    compositeConfiguration.addConfiguration(fichierConfigEquipeDev);
}
```

Now, with Maven I just want to externalize my file properties :

```
private static final String ENV_FILE = "basedir_conf_dir";
private static final String CONFIGURATION_FILE = "configuration/appli.properties";
private static final String DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILE = "configuration/default-appli.properties";
```

I want :

- in my eclipse environnement in src/main/resources/configuration
- in my package in basedir (at the same level of my jar file)

`-- package complete
   |_ myApplication.jar
   |_ appli.properties
   |_ default-appli.properties`

**Can you help me to change url of my properties files with Maven ?**

Comment: Properties should be located into `src/main/resources` if will become part of the resulting jar if you need them only for tests put them into `src/test/resources`

Comment: ok but I want to be able to change properties after installation of my application whitout recompile all. Just change properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your "default.properties" in src/main/resources/configuration. Then add to your pom.xml, in the build section:

```
<resources>
        <resource>

            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/configuration</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>default.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
             <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

See [Maven the reference guide](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html) for more details

Comment: Do not repeat the defaults!

Comment: First of all I'm not sure that if you want to add different resources directory, you need to include the default one. Also, if you want to modify the default directory, (like here with src/main/resources/configuration), it would be a good practice to list every resource directory (including the default one)

Comment: The configuration folder is a sub folder of src/main/resources so no need to make a supplemental configuration. The convention is having resources in `src/main/resources` no need explicitly list each resource would make pom's files containing many lines which are not needed and is against the paradigm `Convention over Configuration`.

Comment: And how do you override the target path?

Comment: My field is correctly at basedir but i have this stacktrace and the url of my properties field is not correct. How can i change it dynamically ?

`Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration2/ex/ConfigurationException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0`

Comment: This is a different question. To change it dynamically, you can do it from your jar with the io/nio APIs. Your stacktrace likely comes from a wrong manifest file, what is your manifest.mf file? Do you have any maven plugin configured to make your jar executable?

Comment: @asettouf Why do you need to overwrite the target? Those property files should be in the jar file they will be by default at the root folder in your jar file...which can be accessed via `getResourceAsStream("/property.name").`?

Comment: That was the question asked, that's why :) You can modify your properties in that case without having to rebuild the whole app, where I can see potential use cases to be honest

Comment: I entered the code with the resources and I use the recommended command line. My properties file is at the root near my jar but I can not seem to use it. How to do ?


`String CONFIGURATION_FILE = "configuration/appli.properties";
String DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILE = "configuration/default-appli.properties";
ConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration> builder1 = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class).configure(params1.fileBased().setURL(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(CONFIGURATION_FILE))));`

Comment: You want a relative path CONFIG_FILE="appli.properties".

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not a star with maven :'( 

Yes when i am in devellopement, it is in the configuration directory and when i deliver it to the client it is at the root of the package

Comment: Then modify the target path in the resources section so it shadows your dev environment